# C++ equivalent of instanceof/extends

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I want to create a resource manager and i have an idea how it should work, but i cant figure out how to set it up accordingly in C++

```
class Resource{
public:
    virtual void loadFromFile();
};

class Texture: public Resource{
public:
    void loadFromFile(){ do texture specific loading }
};

class Mesh: public Resource{
public:
    void loadFromFile(){ do mesh specific loading }
};

class ResourceManager{
private:
    vector<Resource*> resources;
public:
    template <typename T>
    void addResource(){
        T* resource = new T;
        resource->loadFromFile();
        resources.push_back(resource);
    }
};
```

How can I enforce that the `T` is extending `Resource` and is not a class that happens to have a method with the same name?

Comment: you can use sfinae, which version of C++ are you using?

Comment: `resources.push_back(resource)` will fail to compile if `T` doesn't inherit from `Resource`.

Comment: Since C++20, constraints and concepts may be useful.

Comment: I don't see how `instanceof` is relevant. Java has the same restriction of not being able to shove non-derived objects into a base reference (as in it won't compile, just like C++). No `instanceof` needed for that.

Answer (score 2):

To get a nice friendly error message, you might like to use [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void addResource(){
    static_assert (std::is_base_of_v<Resource, T>, "T must derive from Resource");
    ...
```

This will generate an error at compile time if `T` does not derive from `Resource`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `resources` vector has type `Resource*`, if you try to insert something that is not a derived of `Resource`, you will get a compile time error.

Otherwise you can you SFINAE:

```
class ResourceManager{
private:
    std::vector<Resource*> resources;
public:
    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Resource, T>, void> addResource(){
        T* resource = new T;
        resource->loadFromFile();
        resources.push_back(resource);
    }
}
```

Use SFINAE only if you want to do something else if `T` is not a derived of `Resource`, otherwise you can perfectly rely on the compile time error on `resources.push_back(pointer)`

EDIT:
You can actually force that `T` is a derived of `Resource` using the type system:

```
void addResource(){
    Respurce* resource = new T;
    resource->loadFromFile();
    resources.push_back(resource);
}
```

But only if `loadFromFile` is declared on `Resource` and not in `T` (so on your example will work)
(Thanks to @ RemyLebeau)

Comment: Also, if you change `T* resource` to `Resource* resource`, then the compiler has another failure point if `new T` can't be assigned to a `Resource*`

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are right, i'll add it at the answer

Comment: Resoirce* resource = new T(); with this, if i call loadFromFile, it will use the derived class implementation? Somewhere at some point i read that it wont work because of some weird thing.

Comment: @MarkoTaht, Slicing perhaps? That doesn't apply to pointers.

Comment: @MarkoTaht you have marked that method as `virtual`, so there will be a runtime evaluation of which function will be called, and so in this case, if your `T` override that method with a new implementation, that function will be called (in other words, the derived method will be called, not the one in the base class, and so it will have the behavior that you expect it to have)

Comment: @chris well i think that can be either slicing or passing by value, which will cause a call to the base classe method, but i'm with you about that this cases does not apply to neither of this two